# Multi-people picker in approval workflow

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

Is it possible to start a workflow which assigns approval tasks for an item to multiple people with a people picker field? My customer wants several people picker fields in the following format:

"Must Approve All" - all items must be approved by these users
"$100 Approvals" - all items with a total price of $100 must be approved by these users

Is this possible or do I need to create some sort of event receiver to save these names into hidden fields (e.g., 100 Approval - 1) since they're 100% adamant about having a single field for this?

Answer (score 0):

Collect feedback" should work for your needs. You should do something like this:

> Create a new Tasks list, called "Reading List" Add the Collect
>   Feedback workflow to the list Add the group or users you want to
>   assign tasks to in the "reviewers" field Configure the workflow like
>   so:
>
> set it to assign tasks in parallel so all members get a task
>   simultaneously set "expand groups" so if you add a group to reviewers,
>   each group member gets a task set a due date and duration if you want
>   Now, when you add a new item (book) to your "reading list" list, it
>   will assign a task to all the reviewers (readers.)

Or you can create a group, add users in that group and assign the task to group.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/sharepoint-designer-help/assign-a-form-to-a-group-in-a-workflow-HA010233624.aspx